# ERP system written in SQL Server, Trigger job not running

Tags: sql-server, erp

We are a manufacturing plant that runs off an ERP system written in SQL Server.  I have never worked with SQL and therefore do not know the language.  What I do know is that a trigger job that was running and updating data for us, is now NO longer running.  Is anyone familiar enough to answer any questions about this for me???  Any help would certainly be appreciated!

Thanks,

Jana

Answer (score 0):

well someone could have disabled the trigger, someone could have deleted the trigger or someone could have changed the trigger.

Here is code to enable all triggers on a table:

ALTER TABLE mydatabse.dbo.mytable ENABLE Trigger ALL

or you could just enable the one trigger that is disabled.

If that doesn't work, it is one of the other two possibilities. YOu do have a backup right? or all the code properly stored in source control so you can revert to the eralier verision if need be. If you do though, find out why the triiger was chaged or deleted. Proably it was interfering with another process and the people who did that weren't professional enough to find out if the trigger init's current form was still needed.